# passing parameters in ngClass conditional function

Tags: angular, ng-class, ngfor

I have a users selection slider that has list of users with their name and profile picture. And i am trying to create a selection and deselection mechanism for user's slider.

I have an array of users that i am using `*ngFor` to parse. When any of those users is clicked i am adding class "active" to `<li>` containing user (clicked for second time and class is removed.) info for current user in `*ngFor`. I am also making an array of user id's which are clicked and removing the id's that are clicked for a second time.

Now if any object of "helpers" array (another array that is defined in component. Both users array and helpers array is coming from server as JSON) has user id equal to user in current iteration then "active" class should be added automatically while view is being rendered.

I am using *ngClass to add "active" class like this `[ngClass]="{active: checkIfUserIsHelper(friend.id, helpers)}"`. But the problem is that i cannot access helpers in `checkIfUserIsHelper` function. that is in my component. I have tried to access helpers via `this.helpers` but its not working as well.

my html:

```
<ul class="slides">
  <li class="select {{friend.id}}" [ngClass]="{active: checkIfUserIsHelper([friend.id], [helpers])}" *ngFor="let friend of friendsList" (click)="addHelper(friend)">
    <div class="">
      <img src="{{friend.profile_image}}" alt="user-img" />
      <p class="flex-caption">{{friend.full_name}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="friendsList == false" >No friends found</li>
</ul>
```

my function checkIfUserIsHelper:

```
checkIfUserIsHelper(id: number, helpers: any){
    console.log("Parameters: ",id, helpers);
    //Logic to check presence in array goes here
    return false;
  }
```

my function addHelper:

```
addHelper(data: Object) {
    let index = this.helpers.indexOf(data);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.helpers.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.helpers.push(data);
    }
}
```

if i use [ ] around helper in function call then friends is undefined.

How do i solve add class to selected users and add them to array?

Is my approach correct?

Comment: `checkIfUserIsHelper([friend.id], [helpers])` will be called **a lot** when you bind to in in the view. It's usually better to assign the value to a property and bind to that property instead.

Comment: So i should use `(click)="addHelper()"` to change the value of the property that is bound with `*ngClass`?

Comment: That's a possibility. I don't fully understand what you try to accomplish. The value you bind to in `ngClass` could also need to be updated when a value changes that you use to calculate in `checkIfUserIsHelper()`

Comment: In our application there are tasks each task has helpers for it. Now i have two API calls one returns all the users in app i.e users other returns users that are specific to that task. I have to display all the users but the users that are specific to task should display differently. and if a you would want to change the helpers for task you can simply remove it by clicking pre selected user.